# XUL textbox is not editable or visible

Tags: xul

When using an XUL `<textbox>` element in the latest Firefox releases, I am not able to focus the element and write something into it. It worked in older versions, like 33. Using `html:textarea` instead seems to work.  However, I would be happy to keep the original XUL element in my app and want to understand what is going wrong here.

When using the `multiline` attribute on the `<textbox>` element, the element is not visible at all!

Any hint or explanation would be great.

Here is my small *test.xul* file content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/global.css" type="text/css"?>

<window
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
  xmlns:html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  width="800"
  height="800">

<textbox flex="1" />
<html:textarea flex="1" />

</window>
```

Comment: What version of Firefox? After testing, this appears to work fine in FF49.0.2 and Developer Edition (51.0a2) (with and without adding `multiline="true"`). Do you mean doing something other than clicking within the element (or using Tab to focus) and typing something into the field?

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for testing. I tested it using FF 49.0.2 and Windows 10. The regression range seems to be between 37 (working) and 38 (broken). Strange that it works for you. But even more strange that it's not working for me as I don't believe they changed anything here.

Comment: I was also testing with Windows 10. It looks like there is something else going on. I put the file (both as you provided and with multiple additional fields of each type, mixing in `multiline="true"`) in a directory which I can access from a `chrome://` URL and just loaded the URL into a page in the browser. I can test it as a independent window (e.g. a dialog), if that is what you were doing.

Comment: When/if you add the original contents of your *chrome.manifest* to the question, please leave me a comment, including `@Makyen` so I can remove my down-vote (and possibly up-vote) and retract my close-vote. The down-vote is because in order to determine the answer to the Question requires non-obvious information which is not contained in the Question.

Comment: @Makyen I've allready added the relevant part of the chrome.manifest to my answer. Everything else in that file has nothing to do with the issue and might be confusing. But maybe I just don't get what you are asking for. The thing is, that the new textcontext.dtd contains additional strings which where not part of my dtd. As the additional strings are part of the textbox binding and are not found in my dtd, the textbox didn't worked at all.

Comment: Without more information in your Question, the only way someone could come up with your Answer as the answer to your problem would be to be psychic. As such, the question is incomplete. Questions need to contain enough information to be answerable. Right now, your question only indicates that you have a problem for which more information is needed. What is actually needed is *at least* that line from your *chrome.manifest* and, *at a minimum*, a description of your *xulrunner_global_textcontext.dtd*, including the basis from which it was made and any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.
I had an override rule in my chrome.manifest file which looked like this:

```
override chrome://global/locale/textcontext.dtd 
         chrome://myapp/locale/xulrunner_global_textcontext.dtd
```

The file was changed for firefox 38 and an additional ENTITY was added which is not defined in my file. Adding the missing ENTITY solved all problems.

Thanks Makyen for testing and inspiration.

The changes for those who are interested:
https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/l10n/mozilla-beta/de/diff/6f25b6d2dcf5/toolkit/chrome/global/textcontext.dtd

Comment: Please add the contents of your original *chrome.manifest* to the question. Without that information this answer makes no sense. In other words, without that information in the Question, someone would have to be psychic to be able to tell that this was the answer to the question.  Questions need to contain enough information such that an answer can be determined. Please leave a comment for me, including `@Makyen` when/if your update the question.

Comment: Note:To be compatible with multiple Firefox versions where you need to change an override, you will need to use the `appversion` manifest flag on the line and declare multiple overrides with different files. Doing so is frustrating. While you can have multiple `appversion` flags on each line, they are *OR*ed together. In other words, you can't say `appversion<=41.* appversion>=40.0` to get just within the range 40.0–41.* (note: `*` always means *largest*, not *any*). Using those two `appversion` flags together would actually specify *all* versions as all versions are either <=41.* OR >=40.0.

Comment: The [`appversion` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#appversion) is also quite version specific. You may need to specify ESR releases explicitly, as the fact that they are ESR is part of the string against which `appversion` is checked. I need to look at the Firefox source code to see if there is a way to optimize specifying a range. For instance: Find out if a second override for the same URL later in the *chrome.manifest* supersedes a prior specification which also matches the `appversion`.

Comment: If that were the case, then you could use successive lines that say `>= 40.0` then next line with a different file `>= 41.0`.  At the moment, the add-on in which I use an override explicitly states each separate possible version in the applicable range and then one at the end with `>=`, which is a pain in the rear.